# use js functions return value for html form action attribute

Tags: javascript, html, get

I want to use the return value of a JS function as the URL for a form get action. Is it possible or do I need to set the form attributes with a function call in the onSubmit attribute?

edit: this is basically what i want to do

```
<div class="search">
    <form method="get" action="https://duckduckgo.com/" id="search-form">
        <input id="searchbar" type="text" name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" autofocus="autofocus"/>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("search-form").action = "bang()";
    </script>
</div>
```

the bang function is an implementation of the bang system from DDG in JS, so i can easily add bangs to a searchbox in my webpage.

Comment: Do you mean you have a javascript function that returns a URL and in the process of doing something else, you want to call that function and set the action attribute of the form?

Comment: `form.action = yourFunction();` will do it.

Comment: i want to call that function when the user submits the form, and have the function be evaluated and the url it returns used for the get request

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [onsubmit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit) event for the form to set the action before the actual submit happens.

```html
<form id="testForm" methods="get" action="#" onsubmit="setFormUrl()">
    Search: <input type="text" name="q" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

```js
function bang()
{
    return "http://www.google.com";
}

function setFormUrl()
{
    var url = bang();
    document.getElementById('testForm').setAttribute('action', url);
}
```

Comment: yeah, that was my alternative plan, but i wanted to know whether there was any way to get the function specified in the action attribute to be evaluated before the get request, instead of the browser trying to load a page generated by the function.